# Interface mocking works improperly

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm writing a test and trying to mock an interface IMyResponse. But it returns int after mocking. Here is what I do:

```
public interface IMyResponse extends Serializable {
    // ...
    Object getResponseObject();
}

private IMyResponse myResponse;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    myResponse = mock(IMyResponse.class);
}

@Test
public void mockTest(){
    // myResponse.getResponseObject() is 0
    when(myResponse.getResponseObject()).thenReturn("value");
    // myResponse.getResponseObject() is 46
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[help-me]` Nothing is obviously wrong. Please provide code we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you annotated the test class with :
`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` ?

Comment: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyResponseTest {

  private IMyResponse myResponse;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    myResponse = mock(IMyResponse.class);
  }
  @Test
  public void mockTest(){
   
    when(myResponse.getResponseObject()).thenReturn("value");
    System.out.println(myResponse.getResponseObject());
  }
}
` works perfectly fine. Not sure what you are doing

Comment: I can not provide more details because this interface is a part of a big library. When I change this interface to child class it works properly. may be you have idea what can be wrong?

Comment: the annotation is @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

Comment: Change it for MockitoJUnitRunner and try again

Comment: It's espresso test so I need @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

Comment: Ok, I think you are missing the @Mock annotation before `private IMyResponse myResponse;`

Comment: I added annotation but it's still the same

Comment: Delete the setUp method and use only the Mock annotation.

Comment: and the response is null now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing mockito version helped(it was 1.10):

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.15.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this self answer. Please also mark it as solution by checking the "accepted" mark.